# How to draw a an empty equilateral triangle with stars and whitespaces " "

Tags: java

[image]

**I am new to java and couldn't figure out how to draw that kind of triangle. I looked at some answers but they all had stars in the triangle. Is there a way that I can add both stars and whitespaces at the same time?**

Comment: You use different loops to print starts or whitespaces, changing dynamically the number of whitespaces you print based on the row you're at.

Comment: I guess we have use two for loops but as I mentioned, I couldn't figure out how to organize the loops.

Comment: You're asking us to do your homework, that's not gonna happen. What did you try so far? Show us some code so we have something to pinpoint.

Comment: This is not about Java, your question is about logic. write out the steps in natural language, and then, try to implement it in code

Comment: Thanks for "think it once more" suggestions guys. I will go on with the first answer and if it doesn't work, then I can ask the code part

Answer (score 2):

Since this looks like a homework question I am not going to answer it directly but I will give you a hint.

Looking a the note, it says that there is no white space on last line, so if you take that into account is easy to do the last line right? Start with a * and then print a space, and so on until you complete this line. Now think about how to do the previous one w.r.t to the this one, it should not be difficult. Once you know how to generate the lines, store them in an array and at the end print it in reverse order.

Comment: Thanks for the array hint. I will try it once more on that way

Comment: I would definitely not use an array, you're adding unnecessary layers of complexity. Printing strings out should be enough.

Comment: @Ssr1369 It is a choice of simple solution to suggest an easier approach to the question asker. Of course it can be done directly, but involves more calculation.